# Unable to Launch IIS Express Web Server - VS 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

I am developing a web project and I am not being able to test it using the IIS Express from the Visual Studio 2015.

I have googled this error and I found many references to it on the internet, but I believe that my case is different, because there is no other error message displayed besides "Unable to Launch IIS Express Web Server".

I've looked at the Windows Event Viewer and I got these errors below:

```
The worker process failed to initialize correctly and therefore could not be started.  The data is the error.

The Module DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\aspnetcore.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.
```

I also tried to launch the IIS Express directly using: `c:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /trace:error` and I was successfull, so I think that the problem must be somewhere within Visual Studio and that my port (8080) is free.

Does anyone knows what else I can do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are working with .NET core/ASP.NET core application then
   please make sure you have installed these-

- .NET Core SDK
- VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

If it is appeared to be solution-specific then-

- Look for applicationhost.config file at `<solution-name>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config` location
- Try removing this file and run solution again.

See if this helps.

Comment: Hi, everything started working once Visual Studio was updated. Thanks for the help!

Comment: To save time I removed ".vs" folder and it worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error few days ago.  I tried many things but i think Repairing `DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe` fixed the issue.

Also, check whether you can run the web app in Kestrel web server. If you can run then worth checking web.config file for the presence of `aspnetCoreModule` tag properly.

This link might be helpful -- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1583